# How to cope with Mouse-Wheel-Delta cross platform?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, mouse, mousewheel, delta

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753123/why-is-wheeldelta-120/16541765), asking why Wheel-Delta is supposed to be `120` on Windows platforms. However, I encounter the same threshold on Linux and Mac. As the value nowadays might change, how do I get the Wheel-Delta on Windows, Linux and Mac? We are using OpenSceneGraph, Boost and Qt for cross-platform development. Maybe they might help here. (It's a C++ project)