# Looking for WHEEL_DELTA constant

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am handling a mouse wheel event in a UserControl which inherits NumericUpDown

```vb
Private Sub MyUpDown_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseWheel
    Me.Value += e.Delta * Me.Increment ' / WHEEL_DELTA
End Sub
```

`MouseEventArgs.Delta` has this tooltip:

> Gets a signed count of the number of detents the mouse wheel has
>   rotated, multiplied by the WHEEL_DELTA constant. A detent is one notch
>   of the mouse wheel.

However I can't find this constant. It is *usually* 120, but I don't want to bank on usually. How can I expose it to my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is WheelDelta = 120?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753123/why-is-wheeldelta-120)

Comment: @LarsTech If you can show me on that page how I can get this constant, I will agree. But I don't.

Comment: `e.Delta` has the constant - whatever it may be - taken into consideration; its the result so why care?

Comment: @Plutonix does it? e.Delta is 120 so does that mean I am scrolling 120 ticks? No. I need to divide by WHEEL_DELTA (120 in most cases). Right now my code is `Me.Value += e.Delta * Me.Increment / 120` but a different mouse may have a different WHEEL_DELTA <> 120

Comment: no, it means you scrolled 1 detent and WHEEL_DELTA is 120 in this case.  e.Delta = ticks * WHEEL_DELTA (see your post).  You'd only need WHEEL_DELTA if you were working backwards to determine ticks/detents, or doing something in WndProc

Comment: @Plutonix so this code: `Me.Value += e.Delta * Me.Increment / 120` is ok?

Comment: Use SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to MSDN `Most applications should check for a positive or negative value rather than an aggregate total.`  in most cases, I have only seen 1 detent movement per click - they might come in rapid succession, but 1 tick (e.Delta=120) per click.

To get the MouseWheel delata factor:

```
 WheelDelta As Integer = SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta
```

it is a member of System.Windows.Forms along with all sorts of other metrics like scroll thumb width etc.