# Mapbox.GL: scroll zoom in and out to specific coordinates on custom mapbox map

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I have embedded a custom mapbox studio map onto my site and set the minZoom and maxZoom coordinates so it only zooms out to a certain zoom level and zooms in to a certain zoom level.  BUT when the user zooms back in, the map goes where the user places their mouse pointer, rightly so, BUT I want it to zoom back to it's starting point, not where the user places their mouse pointer.
This is the closest example I found, but I don't want the narrative, I want the user to just scroll on the map:  https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/scroll-fly-to/

How do I make it such that when the user scrolls down the embedded map zooms out to a certain set of coordinates and when the user scrolls back up, the embedded map zooms back in to a certain set of coordinates?

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8',
center: [-118.451784, 34.035947], // starting position
zoom: 11.66,
maxZoom: 11.66, // starting zoom
minZoom: 1.4, // ending zoom
doubleClickZoom: false,
dragRotate: false,
dragPan: false
```

});

Comment: Curiously enough, zooming to fixed coordinates happens to be the out-of-the-box behaviour if setting coordinates via [React Mapbox GL](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl). To get closer to the default mapbox behaviour, look at their `onDragEnd` event.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this isn't easy with the existing mapbox-gl-js API. I recommend [disabling all the built-in interaction handlers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/interactive-false/) and writing your own event handler for the [`wheel` event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onwheel.asp) that calls [`Map#setZoom`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map.setZoom)